# Unexpected behaviour while constructing higher order functions in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to construct a function in Python that accepts a list of numbers and returns a list of functions dependent on the input values:

```
filters = lambda ys: [lambda x: x % y == 0 for y in ys]
```

If I call the above `filters` function with a list of values, it should return a list of lambda functions which have been constructed from the input list. For example, calling `filters([3,5])` should return

```
[lambda x: x % 3 == 0,
 lambda x: x % 5 == 0]
```

Defining another function, `applyToNum` (similar to `map`) as

```
applyToNum = lambda x, fns: [fn(x) for fn in fns]
```

I now encounter the following behaviour:

```
applyToNum(15, filters([3,4,5]))     

# returns [True, True, True] rather than [True, False, True]
```

The interesting thing is that if I construct the `filters` function list manually, it works as expected:

```
filters2 = [
  lambda x: x % 3 == 0,
  lambda x: x % 4 == 0,
  lambda x: x % 5 == 0]

applyToNum(15, filters2)

# returns [True, False, True]
```

Could someone explain why the above behaviour is seen?

Comment: Python closures are late binding; `y` is not evaluated until the lamba(s) are called, at which point the value on the stack is the final iteratee value from `ys`

Comment: That explains it. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, you could fix this with code like this: `filters = lambda ys: [(lambda y: lambda x: x % y == 0)(y) for y in ys]`, or this might be easier to read: `def filter_func(y): return lambda x: x % y == 0`; `filters = lambda ys: [filter_func(y) for y in ys]`

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks.